# is delete guaranteed to delete from a hash in golang?

Tags: go

I have a hash like this:

```
  var TransfersInFlight map[string]string = make(map[string]string)
```

And before I send a file I make a key for it store, send it, delete it:

```
  timeKey := fmt.Sprintf("%v",time.Now().UnixNano())
  TransfersInFlight[timeKey] = filename
  total, err := sendTheFile(filename)
  delete(TransfersInFlight, timeKey)
```

i.e. during the time it takes to send the file, there is a key in the hash with a timestamp pointing to the filename.

the func `sendTheFile` always either works, or has an err but never throws a stacktrace exception and crashes the whole program so the line:

```
  delete(TransfersInFlight, timeKey)
```

should be called 100% of the time. And yet, I sometimes find cases where it's like this line was never called and the file is stuck in TransfersInFlight forever. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you accessing the map in multiple places concurrently? Run your code with the race detector.

Comment: oh I just need a mutex? I thought golang had atomic ops on hash like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but _no_ values in Go are safe for concurrent reads and writes. The only "atomic" operations are through the "sync/atomic" package.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are not safe for concurrent access. I would do this either using a mutex to moderate map access or having a goroutine reading either a channel of "op" structs or have a "add" channel and a "delete" channel.

You're probably safe having multiple read-only accesses concurrently, but once you have writes in the mix, you really want to ensure you only have one access at a time.

If you are set on using a goroutine to manage the count, one way would be something like:

```
import "sync/atomic"

var TransferChan chan int32
var TransfersInFlight int32

func TransferManager() {
  TransfersInFlight = 0
  for delta := range TransferChan {
    // You're *probably* safe just using +=, but, you know...
    atomic.AddInt32(&TransfersInFlight, delta)
  }
}
```

That way, you only need to do `go TransferManager()` and then pass your increments and decrements over the `TransferChan` channel.

Comment: thanks for the chan and operation idea. that's such a good idea. made the code more simple too.

Comment: @AndrewArrow I took the liberty of replacing your image with in-line code.